# Can you restore old Magento catalog and product data?

Tags: magento2, module, catalog, products, data

our Magento catalog database has undergone an update which mixed items together and caused chaos.
Can we somehow extract old product data (product numbers, categories, which products were contained in subcategories etc) from before the update ?
Preferably in a form of Excel or some exportable format

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of your Magento 2 database from before the update, you can restore the old catalog and product data from that backup. You can use a database management tool such as phpMyAdmin to import the backup file and overwrite the existing database.

If you do not have a backup of the old catalog and product data, you can still try to extract the data from the database using SQL queries. You can use a tool like MySQL Workbench or Navicat to run queries on your Magento 2 database.

Here are some example queries you can use to extract product data:

To extract a list of all products with their SKU, name, and price:

```
 SELECT sku, name, price FROM catalog_product_entity;
```

To extract a list of all categories with their name and path:

```
 SELECT cce.path, ccev.value FROM catalog_category_entity AS cce
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS ccev ON cce.entity_id = ccev.entity_id AND ccev.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE entity_type_id = 3 AND attribute_code = 'name');
```

To extract a list of all products and their categories:

```
 SELECT ccev.value AS category, cpe.sku, cpe.name FROM catalog_category_product cp
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity AS cce ON cp.category_id = cce.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS ccev ON cce.entity_id = ccev.entity_id AND ccev.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE entity_type_id = 3 AND attribute_code = 'name')
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe ON cp.product_id = cpe.entity_id;
```

These queries will give you the data in a tabular format that you can export to CSV or other formats. Note that you may need to modify the queries based on the structure of your database and the attributes you want to extract.